# Http request headers are not taken into account by angular service workers dataGroups configuration

Tags: service-worker, angular-service-worker, cachestorage

I am in reference to **angular service workers** and `dataGroups` configuration as documented here: https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-config#datagroups.

I have configured my `dataGroups` as follows:

```
  "dataGroups": [
    {
      "name": "api-performance",
      "urls": [
        "/api/referential/**"
      ],
      "cacheConfig": {
        "strategy": "performance",
        "maxSize": 100,
        "maxAge": "3d"
      }
    }
  ]
```

It now caches all http requests which match the pattern.

However, we also pass a custom http request header (i.e. `x-project-id: 8545dbf0-6e8b-47b0-b5ad-874415b20b63`) upon which the http response will depend.

Thus, for two different `x-project-id` values, the content of the response will be different.

Let's see an example:

First GET request:

Url: `/api/referential/xxx`
Header: `x-project-id: foo`

Second GET request:

Url: `/api/referential/xxx`
Header: `x-project-id: bar`

Unfortunately, with my current configuration, angular service workers will cache the first request and return the content of the response for the first request regardless of whether my custom header has changed...

Is this by design ?

Is there a way to ensure the custom http headers are taken into account by angular service workers or do I have to pass the `project Id` in the url?

Comment: After looking a little into docs, to let CacheAPI know that headers, and which headers, are importants, you need tu use Header `Vary`, maybe you're missing it ? 
You can find more information here : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Cache/match and here : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Vary

Comment: Thanks a lot @ekans. This looks like the features I am looking for. However, I am not sure whether or how the angular framework will let me customize the sw configuration to allow using the features you kindly suggested. I am going to investigate and post here accordingly.

Comment: I would be very grateful if anyone could provide links or pointers as to how to customize angular service workers!